How to access or use PaddleOCR API for handwritten text purposes (this is for my mobile application)?
I'm a beginner building an Android mobile app which has a feature of detecting handwritten texts. I noticed that one of the good models available and is for free is the PaddleOCR. However, the Github documentation is kinda difficult for me to understand as of this moment and I was only available to make it work in my Google Colab evironment using the quick start tutorial they provided. However, again, my goal is to access this for my mobile app, which I think is through API or maybe deploying it locally (though this may be much more difficult).
How can I do or use PaddleOCR for my mobile app to detect handwritten text? What method do you recommend I should do?
I tried using the Quick start tutorial only which is installing the package and running it in my environment. I got it to work but I'm not sure how I can use this using an API only.

"I'm a beginner building an Android mobile app" -- PaddleOCR does not seem to be suitable for beginner Android developers at this time. The instructions indicate that it would be a challenge for an experienced developer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
